# usage of select null?

Tags: sql, select, null

I see that some examples uses select statement with null. When to use:

```
select null from etc. etc.?
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Select null is usually used in combination with EXISTS.
>
> eg:- `IF EXISTS( select null from ...)`

It sets up the Exists status as true if there are records in the select query.
Check this link which has some interesting comments on the usage of select null with Exists: [SQL SERVER- IF EXISTS(Select null from table) vs IF EXISTS(Select 1 from table)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/21/sql-server-if-existsselect-null-from-table-vs-if-existsselect-1-from-table/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it explains well. Also IF EXISTS(Select 1 from table) is same with IF EXISTS( select null from ...) according to performance? I am not sure..

Comment: @kamaci - tough performance is same or not, it is negligible. So no need to bother. :))

Answer (score 23):

Linq to SQL do this sort of thing :

```
Select * 
From Foo f 
Where Exists
(   
    Select null 
    From Bar b 
        on b.fooId = f.id
)
```

It prevents to bring data when I don't want data, but just the exist status.

Comment: I am not so sure about it. You might check this: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/age-old-select-vs-select-1-debate.html It seems that for the exists sentence, it does not evaluate whatever the inner select what to expand. :)