# Which Way Is Better To Fetch List Of Parameters From Table?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a requirement to fetch list of configuration parameters from Mysql table(foo). Can you please suggest which approach gives better performance?

```
Table: foo
--------------------
id|params    |value
--------------------
1  param1     yes
2  param2     12
3  param3     true
--------------------
```

Approach 1:

```
String param1Val = query.call("select value from foo where params='param1'");
String param2Val = query.call("select value from foo where params='param2'");
......
```

Approach 2:

```
String param1Val[] = query.call("select value from foo where params in('param1', 'param2')");`
```

Comment: The second cause you're making only one call vs. two calls in the first approach.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458096/how-bad-is-in-operator-for-sql-query-perfomance)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 is better as it will decrease your turn around time by making single call. However, then you need to consider quering parameter name along with value to know the mapping.

Comment: But in query will take more process time for non indexed columns right?

Comment: I believe you are making call from some other machine (application server or something) , so network latency till database server will be far more than query time.

Answer (score 0):

Use of an IN parameter is internally translated to an OR:
SELECT value FROM foo WHERE params='param1' OR params='param2'; This can lead to not using present indexes (IN statements can misbehave very quickly), leading to poor query performance. This is really situation dependent, and can even change due to data growth (new histograms for the optimizer).

If your table now has 1000s of values, an index on 'params' and it is only 2 values: Use your IN.

If your IN will contain more values: Beware of the change in behaviour.

Comment: OP is calling from someother application , so I believe whatever performance query will give. It will be less time than network latency.

Comment: @Panther It really depends: Once mysql starts with full table scans, pretty much everything else is quicker. I agree however that network latency is however a killer in a many query scenario.