# Multiple Small Queries Faster Than One Big Query

Tags: sql

The 'big' query below runs for 24+ hours:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE COL_A IN (a, b, c, ...) 
  AND COL_B IN (d, e, f, ...)
```

In contrast, dividing this 'big' query into multiple 'small' queries and executing them simultaneously finishes in 30 mins:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE COL_A IN (a) AND COL_B IN (d)

SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE COL_A IN (a) AND COL_B IN (e)

...

SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE COL_A IN (b) AND COL_B IN (d)

SELECT * 
FROM VIEW 
WHERE COL_A IN (b) AND COL_B IN (e)

...
```

If it's relevant, each IN statement in 'big' query contains about 30 items. Hence, 900 unique 'small' queries = 1 'big' query.

Note that `VIEW` is defined as a query off of `VIEW_1` which is itself a query off of `VIEW_2` which is itself a query off of `VIEW_3`. Each VIEW is millions of rows long.

I'd reverse engineer the views and write my own single query for exactly what I want. However, I don't have SELECT access to the underlying TABLE.

It seems counterintuitive that programmatically writing and executing 900 different queries in parallel (used Python) executes quicker than one big query when the returned table is the same. Why is this?

Attached is a snippet of the 200 operations from the `EXPLAIN PLAN`. [image: Explain Plan For]

Comment: Many reasons. Nesting views like this is a known performance bottleneck. The optimizer has a limited amount of milliseconds to generate a plan. Once it times out, it uses the "best". Which may not be a good plan at all. If your query has millions of rows, it's not going to be a good plan. Having a huge number of `IN` operators gets expanded to `OR` by the optimizer, again contributing to a poor plan when you have 900 of them. Lots of minor "oopsies" stacked on each other here to create a giant performance black hole.

Comment: @JacobH Thanks for the detailed response! Given I can't reverse engineer the views and write my own query (no SELECT access to underlying table), what's my best option here short of having the DB team create a new view? Is it just to continue using Python to programmatically write hundreds of queries, execute them simultaneously, and then combine results?

Comment: Comment was too long but here is a good link to start on [nested views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design) and [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/) and [this post on IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458096/how-bad-is-in-operator-for-sql-query-perfomance)

Comment: If you'd actually like help with this, you need to post the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on your query.  There may be something very obvious, such as a lack of work_mem on your client connection.  Using 30 UNION ALLs is not a good solution to this.

Comment: @Ramfjord Thanks. I've attached a snippet of the Explain Plan. Are there any obvious fixes?

Comment: The explain plan you posted doesn't have the `ANALYZE` component I would need.  If you can run EXPLAIN ANALYZE in a `psql` console, paste the results in explain.depesz.com.  That way you can actually tell how much time was spent within any given component.  One thing I suspect will help your query (no evidence yet), is increasing work_mem on the connection.  EXPLAIN ANALYZE output would tell you exactly how much you need (as you can see there is no info on memory usage in your image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can run these as one query:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE COL_A IN (a) AND COL_B IN (d)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE COL_A IN (a) AND COL_B IN (e)
UNION ALL
. . .
```

It sounds like the underlying tables have indexes on the views.  You can probably also simplify the queries to either:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE COL_A = a AND COL_B IN (d, e, . . .)
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE COL_A IN (a, b, . . .) AND COL_B = d
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test tomorrow and report times for this method - executing a single query with 30 UNION ALL statements.

Comment: @Jack . . . Test one of them first to see which version is faster.