# PHP/MySQLi Page Numbers and Final query issues

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, limit

I am trying to create a page number function that displays 9 results per page from my forum_replies.sql table. My PHP code so far will only display page 1, page 2. Page 1 has 9 query's but page two has none... but there's 22 rows of data that should be fetched, so at least 2 pages should show!

Here's my code!

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] > 1) {
        $currentPage = $_GET["p"];
        $limiter = $currentPage * 9;
} else {
        $currentPage = 1;
        $limiter = 0;
}

$finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE thread_id = '1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " . $limiter . ",9";
```

Figured out that the isset at the top.. $limiter works like this
0,9 = page 1.. correct
18,9 = page 3.. how do I get page 2 (9,9) and so on.. cause it's completely skipping 9,9!

Comment: Instead of Selecting `null` how about selecting some columns? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875745/usage-of-select-null

Comment: The first $laget is just selecting how many rows we have. Please look at the $finalQuery at the bottom.

Comment: Any error messages? & Little bit of a stupid thing, have you actually done `$finalQuery = $DB->query($finalQuery);`?

Comment: Yes I have done that query where I display the data. I will check for errors now.

Comment: Nope there's no database errors.

Comment: I think I figured it out..

If it's page two.. $limiter will be $currentpage * 9. The whole code is skipping a whole 9 querys. So it goes

0,9
18,9
27,9 etc..

so it's missing 9,9! Is this right?? What would I add to my if code at the top to get around this

Answer (score 0):

How about calling echo $db->error; after each query? You can also echo the querys and try them in phpMyAdmin to find out what's wrong. I can't spot a mistake in the finalQuery, at least not syntax-wise.

Comment: I am running the query in Navicat, trying 0,9 then 9,9 then 18,9 and it seems to be selecting it just fine. I think it's an issue with $limiter.