# Record Counts in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SP that INSERT INTO `TBL_DOMAIN` from `TBL_STAGING`, but first I want check table `TBL_STAGING` to make sure the table is not empty before I truncate table `TBL_DOMAIN`, if table `TBL_STAGING` got more than one record then proceed the truncate table `TBL_DOMAIN` then run the INSERT, ELSE message say the table `TBL_STAGING` is EMPTY and exit the SP.  My goal is to make sure the table `TBL_DOMAIN` still have the data even is old.  I'm very new SQL please help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INSERT_ALL_DOMAIN]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN      

 BEGIN TRANSACTION NT_ALL_DOMAIN 
    INSERT INTO  TBL_DOMAIN
        (DOMAIN_NAME,
        DISTINGUISHED_NAME,
        EMAIL_ADDR_I)
    SELECT  DOMAIN_NAME,  
        DISTINGUISHED_NAME,
        EMAIL_ADDR_I
    FROM TBL_STAGING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if TBL_STAGING has data:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TBL_STAGING)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION NT_ALL_DOMAIN 
  INSERT INTO  TBL_DOMAIN
      (DOMAIN_NAME,
      DISTINGUISHED_NAME,
      EMAIL_ADDR_I)
  SELECT  DOMAIN_NAME,  
      DISTINGUISHED_NAME,
      EMAIL_ADDR_I
  FROM TBL_STAGING
  COMMIT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 RETURN 'no data on table'
END
```

Comment: Thanks gonferr, could you explain this line SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TBL_STAGING.  What if the table is emply?  I need to produce a message saying table TBL_STAGING empty.

Comment: you just need to check if table has data, so this "TOP 1 1" is the fastest way to do it. SQL just pick one row and don't care about columns data of that row. You can complete this with ... ELSE RETURN 'No data on table', or you can throw a RAISERROR

Comment: Actually, the `top 1` part is redundant when checking `exists`.

Comment: I use `SELECT NULL` for `EXISTS`.

Comment: Why not just use the simple select * with exists? It is the one place where select * is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lankymart, NULL or 1, I think that makes no difference, but Zohar-Peled the TOP 1, if the table has many, many records will make big difference in performance.

Comment: @gonferr [Answer to usage of select null?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4875788/692942)

Comment: @gonferr not true. An exists checks only for the existence of rows.

Comment: @Lankymart as the post you linked says, it doesn't matter what you use, the performance is the same. :)

Comment: The EXISTS operator (as well as IN, INTERSECT etc) implements a semi-join operator which, effectively, does the same thing. The operator terminates as soon as it finds a **single matching row**. But whether you use `1` or `NULL` doesn't matter just personal preference.

Comment: @gonferr if you really want to see it in action try "if exists(select 1/0 from sometable)". That will NOT throw a divide by zero error.

Comment: All, I have learned a lot from all of you as newbie to SQL.  But I guess is always learning if you want to learn.  @gonferr thank you for your quick responded.